# Is there a way to constraint a function parameter type based on other parameters?

Tags: typescript

```
type ResourceA = { type: 'A', value: 'A1' | 'A2' | 'A3' };
type ResourceB = { type: 'B', value: 'B1' | 'B2' };
type Resource = ResourceA | ResourceB;

function singleParam(resource: Resource) {
  // ...
}

function multiParams<R extends Resource, T extends R['type'], V extends R['value']>(type:T, value: V) {
  // ... type and value should be 
}

// Examples
singleParam({ type: 'A', value: 'A1' });
singleParam({ type: 'A', value: 'B1' }); // type error

multiParams('A', 'A1');
multiParams('A', 'B1'); // no type error
```

[Link to Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOB7ArgJwMYQIJQLxQG8pRIAuKAciwoBooA3AQwBtkJyqBGCqAH0qwAmHvyoBmHgF8A3ACgS0OEjSYAQnkLFw7SqtoMWbDqu59dwqDNnztsBCgzR8Sh5hz8XKiKrmyAZsgAdujAAJaIgVDwoYEA5swQAAqMqIwAtgAUqPZe5J6OAJSEslBQAPRlUAB0NbKS1gHBYRFQacjMYcmpafAAPDBQEAAewBCBACbwdsqOdAAqgyNjk7AA2hQKFAC6dABqi6MTUzDrTKwQ2wB8GQqkc3RnRlC7RQQl5ZU1VVqQUIwTBnOUQAFihmOMoAAjaB1azROIJLrpDJEW4CfSPHRcKQFOTw%20JJFLI1HaDjUB6GLEmHHSD4-aAQVCoRCoWRtDqhJE9DJUfTY3Fs9qdInc3l0CjU3F0wKIemDJks6wVKAASSmwGBjOg-xAUAA7oxdcBZWlGABraAa0JTZiMeDARbpMAJKHauWM5moOgAK2Q9qgzFCFqgMWImqiEHQEQhwydCQA-EA)

Is there any way to make this last example cause a type error, just like in the second example, but only using two parameters (`type` and `value`)?

I tried this [solution](https://dev.to/nas5w/using-typescript-generic-constraints-to-restrict-function-arguments-based-on-other-arguments-1jdi), but it would require me to add a third parameter like `resource: R` to the `multiParams` function. Anyway, in that case, the first fn `singleParam` would be simpler.

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699531/typescript-narrowing-type-from-generic-union-type If that's indeed the case, looks like you're out of luck.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wORbyW) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (If you reply please mention @jcalz so I'll be notified)

Comment: @jcalz thanks!! it works, but unfortunately IDE (vscode, tsplayground) autocomplete doesn't work perfectly. I would like to be able to aucomplete the second parameter based on the the first parameter too.

But I consider it an acceptable answer.

Comment: Would you prefer [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGRMKm) instead? There's a tradeoff between ideal call side behavior and ideal implementation side behavior, and right now your implementation is empty.  Can you test the two suggestions to see if either has unacceptable implications for the implementation (and if so, add enough code to the question to demonstrate this)?  Let me know how I should proceed.

Comment: @jcalz second approach seems to work perfectly. Both solutions are interesting, but the second one fits better to my use case. Thank you!

Comment: @jcalz i don't see need to add more code. Your suggestion fixed exactly what i need. Thanks!

You could send an answer explaining both approaches and I will accept ofc, but please make sure to list your second suggestion as the main answer. The multiParams reflects my actual implementation.

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two approaches.

---

The first is to make `multiParams()` accept a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) which we can immediately [destructure into correlated variables](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) `type` and `value`.  It could look like this:

```
type MultiParamsArgs = Resource extends infer R ? R extends Resource ?
  [type: R['type'], value: R['value']]
  : never : never;

/* type MultiParamsArgs = 
     [type: "A", value: "A1" | "A2" | "A3"] | 
     [type: "B", value: "B1" | "B2"];
*/

function multiParams(...[type, value]: MultiParamsArgs) { }
```

Here I use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over the union in `Resource`, to produce the `MultiParamsArgs` type, which you can see is the union of acceptable types for the argument list of `multiParams()`.

And indeed, calls to `multiParams()` will accept correct parameters and reject incorrect ones:

```
multiParams('A', 'A1');
multiParams('A', 'B1'); // error
multiParams(Math.random() < 0.999 ? "A" : "B", "B1") // error here too
```

A benefit to this approach is that the type checker will interpret the `type`/`value` pair of variables as pieces of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), and you can do narrowing on them accordingly:

```
function multiParams(...[type, value]: MultiParamsArgs) { 
  if (type === "A") {
    const x = { A1: 1, A2: 2, A3: 3 }[value] // okay
  }
}
```

A drawback is that IntelliSense support isn't great; in some sense a union of rest tuples acts like [an overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), but you will sometimes only shown the "first" overload in your editor.  There's an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#31977](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31977) asking for improvement there, but for now this is a limitation.

---

The second approach is to make `multiParams()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the key type `K` of a helper mapping type `MultiParamsMap`, so we can represent the connection between the type `K` of `type` and the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `MultiParamsMap[K]` of `value`.  It could look like this:

```
type MultiParamsMap = { [T in Resource as T['type']]: T['value'] }
/* type MultiParams = {
    A: "A1" | "A2" | "A3";
    B: "B1" | "B2";
} */

function multiParams<K extends keyof MultiParamsMap>(
  type: K, value: MultiParamsMap[K]) { }
```

So `MultiParamsMap` is a [mapped type with remapped keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) over `Resource`.  For most normal calls of `multiParams()`, this accepts correct arguments and rejects incorrect ones.

```
multiParams('A', 'A1');
multiParams('A', 'B1'); // error
```

And IntelliSense is decidedly useful; as soon as you write `multiParams('A',` the compiler infers `"A"` for `K` and then prompts you to provide `"A1" | "A2" | "A3"` for the second parameter.  So that's a benefit.

The drawback here is that the type checker is unable to understand that checking `type` has any effect on `value`, so you can't use them like a discriminated union:

```
function multiParams<K extends keyof MultiParamsMap>(
  type: K, value: MultiParamsMap[K]) {

  if (type === "A") {
    const x = { A1: 1, A2: 2, A3: 3 }[value] // error!
  }

}
```

And in fact it is technically possible to pass in a `value` that doesn't correspond to `type` the way you want:

```
multiParams(Math.random() < 0.999 ? "A" : "B", "B1") // okay?!
```

That is accepted because `K` is inferred as the union `"A" | "B"`, and so `MultiParamsMap[K]` is the full `"A1" | "A2" | "A3" | "B1" | "B2"` union.  And thus `"B1"` is accepted as `"value"` even though there's a 99.9% chance that `type` is `"A"`.  This sort of thing doesn't happen often in practice, so you probably don't have to worry about it from the caller side, but this possibility is one reason why the implementation narrowing doesn't happen.  There are open issues about this at [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) and [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014), but for now this is a limitation.

---

If IntelliSense is the most important concern for you, then you probably want the generic function solution.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkgC4CeMyAStAPYCuATogIJIC8epFEAXEgHIWAgDRIAbpnp9BLAIwCkAH1kAmRSqEBmRQF8A3EW6UkNKA2YQAQhy7lK-AVdESpMpwuWCr6pAcLE9tR0TIi2ZhasXhGh1oZGAGb0wPAkAJa0wEhQacAA5hgQAAogjOAAFIwhlvwxlgCUeEbEAPQtSAB0XUa6AUigkLAIyACqwBnAAPIJZiQAKvQwhVBNzcbIALL0GOklZWBQLIx5K5x1YRAAHiQQwAAmK7kJEIymSAD8b1c39yvnyO81sQANpBWrAgRBAQAXTEkgw0nBAnh0hh0KBSH4wAg4hemP6OJe8WIrQAVOskFsdmk9uBDsdTkgMSTQTx+AAiFjsuFuDnydleTmqAUqTladnQrzMkFgpDsqzc1wImTyuQiuU+CWGElIUktPrEJIpdKZJBgba7Up08pdDqsyg85XQ-hUy37eknRoEDFpBJIcpBDjsTic9le6XwTJQEhIS62XBIeT8ORiFiqfiqVNafhaPzAlEQSVtJC0ADWIDIGN6a16OvN1NpB3KQhcQgU9W1JPrbutLbEHgEHaQxZejFojDW3ZpVqbGxAJAAFh0yvdaGByo0ADxIAAMHQAnIePnKufj5YrVWHh+1R+OkAuXsgSLRaD0+gNoHAwgBxW4vNLwKsOqBq607unOMDxkgwJzEguSmNUYQgCscwQlC0LOkgqHIm4MJ+GsLTkiBFpgXS8bSiwfJqoKabqmK7KdjqxBWByVjUaKmqMX4ur6msRqpBMZokY2UCbgA0kg3y3A8SClhAZC0H6oEiRBAB85QYrKYmOoilLCTOUAQcCYnQuGPp+gGPBBiGXLhkxJKRsA0axlBSZICmibpkgmaJtmSC5ro+ZuEWN6MGOjAAIRVga+GTvp7rNsI-byIOXFTiJiWtmxqXXpJYXjjF6UGeUc6LsuICruuW67geR6fKGZ4KmIl6NMWZYVu8UV9NWuhAA)

Comment: Let's suppose, in the mapper help, instead of mapping like {[string]: string}, I want to map more than one field, like {[string}, {values: string, fieldB: string, fieldC: number}}.

I can't express `value: MultiParamsMap[K]['values']` because typescript gives me this error  `Type '"values"' cannot be used to index type ...`

Is this error related to this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808 ?

Is there any workaround?
Please check this code: https://tsplay.dev/w23jzN

Comment: This looks like a followup question and therefore probably belongs in its own post, since I can't guarantee that I'll get a chance to figure it out and almost nobody else is going to be looking at these comments.  From my brief look at that playground link your `multiParams1()` function has a number of issues, like too many uninferrable type parameters, an erroneous assumption that partial type argument inference is possible, and using deep generic indices, each of which could probably use a lot of discussion and research.  Comments aren't a great place to do any of that.

Comment: I created this other question with a bit more context:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74075239/type-id-cannot-be-used-to-index-type
@jcalz If you have time, please take a look.
Thanks anyway.