# Type '"id"' cannot be used to index type '...'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the code below, both `addThingExample2` and `addThing` have a similar definition. Although `addThingExample2` directly references the union type `Things`, while `addThing` refer to a generic parameter `THING extends Thing`.

`PropsMapper<Things>[TYPE]['id']` works (no type error).

`PropsMapper<THING>[TYPE]['id']` doesn't work (type error: `Type '"id"' cannot be used to index type 'PropsMapper<THING>[TYPE]'.`)

Is there a way I can make this `addThing` function compile without type errors?

```js
type AllowedThingType = 'Smartphone' | 'Toy' | 'Magazine';

type ThingType<TYPE extends AllowedThingType, PROPS extends Record<string, unknown>> = {type: TYPE, props: PROPS};

type ThingTypes = 
  | ThingType<'Smartphone', {color: 'blue' | 'red', price: number}> 
  | ThingType<'Toy', {size: 'small' | 'medium'}>
  | ThingType<'Magazine', {theme: 'nature' | 'games'}>;

type Thing<TYPE extends ThingTypes['type'] = ThingTypes['type'], ID extends string = string> = {id: ID, type: TYPE };

type Things = Thing<'Smartphone', 'Samsung S21'> | Thing<'Smartphone', 'Google Pixel 7'> | Thing<'Toy', 'Sheriff Woody'>;

// Example 1 - no constraints
function addThingExample1(type: Things['type'], id: Things['id'], props: ThingTypes['props']) { /* ... */ }
// the following code will compile fine, but that's not what I want, because it doesn't enforce constraints between the arguments...
addThingExample1('Smartphone', 'Sheriff Woody', { theme: 'nature' });

// Example 2 - with constraints
type TypeProps = { [K in ThingTypes as K['type']]: { props: K['props'] }};
type PropsMapper<T extends Thing> = { [K in T as K['type']]: {id: K['id'], props: TypeProps[K['type']]['props'] }};

// the following code works as expected, typescript help us to make sure you will pass a consistent combination of type, id and props:
function addThingExample2<TYPE extends keyof PropsMapper<Things>>(type: TYPE, id: PropsMapper<Things>[TYPE]['id'], props: PropsMapper<Things>[TYPE]['props']) { /* ... */ }
addThingExample2('Smartphone', 'Sheriff Woody', { theme: 'nature' }); // It works ==> Type error: Argument of type '"Sheriff Woody"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Samsung S21" | "Google Pixel 7"'
addThingExample2('Smartphone', 'Google Pixel 7', { color: 'red', price: 10 }); // It works ==> no type error

// Example 3 - dynamic Thing
class ThingsRepository<THING extends Thing> {

  addThing<TYPE extends keyof PropsMapper<THING>>(type: TYPE, id: PropsMapper<THING>[TYPE]['id'], props: PropsMapper<THING>[TYPE]['props']) {
    // This function has a similar signature to addThingExample2, but it uses a class generic param THING instead of using Things type directly... 
    // How can I make this work?
  }
}

// I would like to use this way:
type MyThings =  Thing<'Smartphone', 'Samsung S21'> | Thing<'Smartphone', 'Google Pixel 7'> | Thing<'Toy', 'Sheriff Woody'>;
const myThingsRepo = new ThingsRepository<MyThings>();
myThingsRepo.addThing('Smartphone', 'Sheriff Woody', { theme: 'nature' }); // It works ==> Type error here...
myThingsRepo.addThing('Smartphone', 'Google Pixel 7', {color: 'blue', price: 10}); // It works ==> No type error here...
```

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA9gdwgEwCoAsCWA7Acw3GgF4oByAZQFsBDAJ2DC0TwgqgB9KNEROPCgFk6BOgC98HANwAoOaEhRs+IiQA8GAJoAFAKJQIAD2AQ8aAM6wEKdKsLFIAGii6ASgHldVI6fNWUO4QAMaIDGgalsAMaq4ArngA1ngoeAB86VDkAN5KEABcKnr6rmAMiGCWRR7eVAC+8ookKriOJNbkclDcrWpOEBrU9EwsbByuOWFIDEUUAEZw8Ry9FAzoFGWxIYVQePE08xAM9VndvQ7qkEN8ApOWOBK7FJb0CIKUNOg4BxSn5zxLgMhqJxFJ2JsoHksBAvnM8HRgPF1h8KOIvpY-ukmvk+oQtCU-GYLNYgR0ANoUfIUAC62TxVwglkp1JprgAkgARIkBazRWKEen8tRZXI4NBFLmufJFHQGKCNBS4y6dBlDWiMZisCGuah0GiWRIEKBUABMAEYKFlAW0COqRlrxpCKABxRCIAhwaC6HDGCBwKAAditF1tN34zqoMNiADMY1AAOrutACbEKAD06ag+mM+rAXqg5qgAFo9ogoGE8Py6PhgJY5DHEiFgDg2FA6GhMLac3mveaABQyhnMqkkWmucWy20j8XjqDlSrVBkDEcLqq0gCUUKg6YAVFAAHRHqC7rP1OSZqDAGFQGOIWzINQVxBoaCPhDPmhgHAFmPSVzzPEwBXlgiIvGWwHIKBwHslAyB0HgwAAaEdDxJY0A4MBaCIEyeBUkYeB3gwOzPlWMQ1oh1hHMAqDmCB0CMAQBzmHWR4HnIHZdmoPZfn2-bDJqYw6pQUbHDgcaJsmdzbtesLPAiSIogqG5NJePH5tApolnBmFYKR1a1vWyokLoFRVPSORQOSADSUD4MuHTttY1ksmONI0kUllrkuLkUN5tIKoquKmYuohgJADBaDyJIMqK242XZeAqE5UC+ayHlQpOqWUrObLzmZS4DCFVQ2a5kC0jSlL+XS9SKheWaybe95II+gphK+cHhEk1h0NYJiQM26DSh0ISxGAwEwnAYBQGhV7lvQSTQIa6xQCAiDxDpH5gL1PX6Tg0QsZ+8z4IirZJYg8b5BOaDthY+WLgUDZNi2bacZc6leqaBLyiYxKBIta3xsVlhhRFWjTpkg4kLKJTXTUBWg8c4NqJY6TknK+iVRQuVbA9bgI3Q4VIyqaMY1j1VbpZe6Hsep4KhxnbvbmvEQKa-EaqM2oTCJ0bifGSYvtJlmyXClAKciKz1CpO5ZuykFdZ0pBZAMRgMBUsywAwTFfIhUAXVeLQUAARKJsb81JRucPtEFOQ8BAIos0DAOW20MPqEBmAweuXYbJv6oagpmuaRu9EbboegWPp+gGgaWwzXGEB9rPsw6Qnc667qet6vr+kGkKWdM4RzOsaCQuUOA7EU5oAAzKTIMtQHLnUMN12RK2WBvKMc6sZlmSdQAAzNpKYIjQFcMnIIRwDtw7BGAiAPM7DAgFoAAS7IAHIutFgSXFkOQKD0b1hhjO-WAD+vA4jkUYOvW+Q0OGNw-joWE2Dt+by6pMlFjOP3VU8NX5ExvnfL+6Mf5VQKpuKE5weiXlUNYRseBmxnSgKBXaDwx7Ty9nbcWK1nbtkZt2ZmGlTQASAnZYCaEmTtgrNPSw1gCDmDEiEecjB9QqFAYlA6HZvYzQeIKFUndoBoBwOsZscAQBsSgLAhuq8UAVgQo3KAC0na4GsMgLqAB+c455zz1WUZo+IcAbpwBwItOa-C1HW3giAR6uJhAgCEeQNUAlOZOl1FQf2RoTQWhDDaNQ9pBJc2dOHLObgc4x38a424kZeYSQFimK08hKzRBUU46cc9yzkHYMgWeEB56L3CCvRxJN+wqTkDQDJKMskHmPmoFOwSPE8zEgkqS+d6KiwoHgyW0tLxN00S3RWysWjd3CGg44EA2KVOqYQSwtT6mEEae44SGcI7Z2jnnSYhcNYLCWNzculdCzVylvXfp8shltyyBvcsuIxle2jFMo8QA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty dirty workaround... it should behave exactly the same, but essentially, we're tricking the compiler into thinking we're giving it the right key (well, we already are, now we're just asserting that it is).

```
class ThingsRepository<THING extends Thing> {
    addThing<TYPE extends keyof PropsMapper<THING>, T extends keyof PropsMapper<THING>[TYPE] & "id", U extends keyof PropsMapper<THING>[TYPE] & "props">(
        type: TYPE,
        id: PropsMapper<THING>[TYPE][T],
        props: PropsMapper<THING>[TYPE][U]
    ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbQ2bN)